# Is there a function in tensorflow 2 where i can create a one dimensional tensor of ones and zeros with equal distance between ones?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am creating a Spiking Neural Network and want to create a spike train with 1000 timesteps that spikes every x timesteps.

```
inp_spikes = tf.reshape(tf.random.categorical(tf.math.log([[((1000-49)/1000), (49/1000)]]), 1*1000), [1, 1000])
```

The above code will give me a tensor with approx 49 ones and the rest zeros but is random. In the interest of reproducibility, I want to take the random out and also have the ones equally spread out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you want a tensor of length 1000, with a `1` every 20 indexes.

There's probably a more simple method, but one way would be to just use a `range`, a `mod`, a comparison to `0`, and a `cast`:

```
inp_spikes = tf.cast(tf.less_equal(tf.mod(tf.range(1000), 20), 0), tf.int32)
```

or alternatively you can use `tf.scatter_nd`:

```
list_of_inds = list(range(0, 1000, 20))
indices = tf.constant([[i] for i in list_of_inds])
updates = tf.constant([1] * len(list_of_inds))
shape = tf.constant([1000])
inp_spikes = tf.scatter_nd(indices, updates, shape)
```

Comment: Thank you Shlomi. I was actually looking to have 20 1s all equally spread - but was able to use your suggestion with a slight tweak and came up with the below

`inp_spikes = tf.reshape(tf.cast(tf.less_equal(tf.math.mod(tf.range(1000), tf.cast(tf.math.floordiv(1000, 20),dtype=tf.int32)), 0), tf.int32), [1, 1000])`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have relatively few non-zero values in the desired tensor, it is best to define it as a sparse tensor:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = 20  # timesteps between spikes and index of first spike
n = 1000  # overall number of timesteps
s = tf.math.floordiv(n, x)  # number of spikes

indices = tf.cast(tf.linspace([x], [n-1], s), tf.int64)  # indices of spikes
values = tf.repeat(1, s)  # values of spikes
dense_shape = [n]  # the dense_shape of the sparse tensor

inp_spikes = tf.sparse.SparseTensor(indices=indices, values=values, dense_shape=dense_shape)

print(tf.sparse.to_dense(inp_spikes))  # just to illustrate the result
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1], shape=(1000,), dtype=int32)
```